# Why does image picker in stateless widget with bloc causes late initialization error?

Tags: flutter, bloc, imagepicker

While using ImagePicker https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker, picking the image works.
But when I put this into the sink it crashes with the following error:

LateInitializationError: Field '_textSeparators@411091221' has already been initialized.

When I remove the FormBuilder it works. So maybe has to do something with the FormBuilder.

Would be great if anyone can point me into the right direction here.

Widget:

```
class CreatePost extends StatelessWidget {
final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _formkey =
GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>(debugLabel: 'GlobalFormKey #SignIn ');
const CreatePost({required Key key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return BlocBuilder<PostBloc, PostState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is AddImagePost) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black,),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            ImagePicker().pickImage(
              source: ImageSource.gallery,)
                .then((im) =>context.read<PostBloc().add(SetImagePost(im!)));
          },
          child: 
          Column(
            children: [
             FormBuilder(key: _formkey, "content")
             _imageWidget(state.memoryImage),
            )],
        ),);
    }
  },
);
}
}
```

Event:

```
class SetImagePost extends PostEvent {
const SetImagePost(this.image);
final XFile image;
}
```

State:

```
class AddImagePost extends PostState {
  final MemoryImage memoryImage;

  AddImagePost(this.image) : super();
}
```

BloC:

```
class PostBloc extends Bloc<PostEvent, PostState> {
final XFile image;

  PostBloc({required this.image})
      :super(CreatePostInit()){
    on<SetImagePost>(_setImagePost);
  }

void _setImagePost(SetImagePost event, Emitter<PostState> emit) async {
  var memoryImage await apiRepository.postImage(event.image);
  emit(AddImagePost(memoryImage));
}
}
```

Adding the different widgets to the FormBuilder step by step, it turned out that exactly the following widget is causing the error:

```
                  TextFieldTags(
                textfieldTagsController: tagsControllerAnswers,
                initialTags: const ["yes","no","maybe"],
                textSeparators: const [' ', ','],
                letterCase: LetterCase.small,
                validator: (String tag) {
                  if (tagsController.getTags!.contains(tag)) {
                    return 'you already entered that';
                  }
                  if(tagsControllerAnswers.getTags!.length > 4){
                    return 'Please enter no more than 5 tags.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                inputfieldBuilder:
                    (context, tec, fn, error, onChanged, onSubmitted) {
                  return ((context, sc, tags, onTagDelete) {
                    return TextField(
                      controller: tec,
                      focusNode: fn,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        isDense: true,
                        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: askTextFieldBorderFocused, width: 3.0),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: askTextFieldBorder, width: 2.0),
                        ),
                        errorText: error,
                        prefixIconConstraints:
                        BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.74),
                        prefixIcon: tags.isNotEmpty
                            ? SingleChildScrollView(
                          controller: sc,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: Row(
                              children: tags.map((String tag) {
                                return Container(
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(3.0),
                                    ),
                                    color: tagColor,
                                  ),
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 5.0),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 5.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      InkWell(
                                        child: Text(
                                          tag,
                                          style: CustomTextStyle.bodyText1(context)?.copyWith(color: tagFont ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          // print("$tag selected");
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(width: 3.0),
                                      InkWell(
                                        child: const Icon(
                                          Icons.close_rounded,
                                          size: 20.0,
                                          color: tagFont,
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          onTagDelete(tag);
                                        },
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              }).toList()),
                        )
                            : null,
                      ),
                      onChanged: onChanged,
                      onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
                    );
                  });
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the "TextFieldTags" out of the FormBuilder solved the issue :)